# Choosing from a collection of items to meet specific feature targets optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I'm having trouble tackling a problem which consists of choosing items from a collection.

I have a collection of items, each item has three features, say X,Y and Z which have a double value

I have a few targets:

1)to reach a specific lower bound for the sum of all the X values of the chosen items.

2)to reach a specific lower bound for the sum of all the Y values of the chosen items.

3)to reach a specific lower bound for the average of all the Z values of the chosen items.

4)minimize the number of items chosen that still meet the above requirements.

I'm not sure what type of optimization algorithms to try, any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. If possible I would like to somehow prioritize my goals and make my bounds "soft" as in, even if they can not all be met in unison still return a "close" selection.

Comment: Do you know the (approximate) size of the collection ?

Comment: Anywhere from 50 to 4000

Comment: If you can have cplex, I am pretty sure the direct modelization I wrote below will be fine.

Comment: Otherwise, I would go for SCIP (http://scip.zib.de/) or the COIN-OR solver.

Comment: My main point is, for a problem of this size, you can use a constraint programming solver or an integer linear solver directly, without writing your own heuristic method. It will be *much* easier for you, and it is likely to be faster than a hand-crafted method, unless you really know what you are doing and spend a lot of time to tune it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, e.g., simulated annealing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

could work really well in this problem.

Just use a suitable softened target function (i.e., penalize for each of the 4 targets that you have) and then start annealing.

Some terminology: this is definitely not linear programming since your variables are binary ones (i.e., is this item included).

If your target function is good enough, you could just use a greedy algorithm to get a reasonable result REALLY fast

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is similar to a knapsack problem. In the knapsack problem you have a certain bag of a certain size and items of a certain size and with a certain value. You then want to maximize the value while not exceeding the size.

However, your problem is a bit different. I would formulate it as minimizing the sum of X, Y and Z values as well as minimizing the number of items and put a constraint on X, Y, and Z which represents your lower bound. With this definition you can see that your problem is actually multi-objective (I assume some of this objectives are conflicting, like the minimization of items with the feasible space). The function that you have to write is called a fitness function that calculates the quality of a certain choice. To deal with the constraint you can either use a penalty that you return as a fitness or if you can treat constraints in the algorithm specify the degree of constraint violation.

I would use a heuristic approach to solve this problem. For this we need to choose a representation (data structure) of a solution to the problem.

As in the knapsack you could choose a binary representation. This means that for every item you have one dimension in your binary vector that is 1 if it is included and 0 if not. The length of the vector is equal to the number of items.

As for solvers there exist many metaheuristics for such a representation. But the closest choice would probably be a genetic algorithm which was developed with binary encoding in mind. If you want to solve the problem in a multi objective way I would choose NSGA-II or SPEA2 as algorithms. If you combine your objectives in a weighted sum approach or by other means into a single value a standard genetic algorithm as defined by John Holland would suffice. Multi-objective algorithms have the advantage that they explore the pareto front of all non-dominated solutions and e.g. result in solutions where X is larger, but Y and Z are not as well as other solutions where e.g. X, Y, and Z are smallest, but the number of items is higher.

The already mentioned simulated annealing algorithm is another metaheuristic for solving such problems. But a priori it is not currently possible to tell which would be working better. However simulated annealing is a bit difficult to configure when you don't know the range of fitness values beforehand, because you need an initial temperature and a cooling schedule that fits this range.

You can also go for simpler construction heuristics that e.g. work in a greedy way (e.g. always taking the item with biggest X, Y, and Z that is either just below or reaches the bounds. But I suppose a metaheuristic will find better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be modelled with a mixed-integer problem. If your collection is not too large (say few hundred values), I would use this model since it will be way easier for you to write this in a standard lp file than to program and parametrize an heuristic.

You can give this problem to a mixed-integer problem solver:

- COIN-OR (free),
- Cplex (commercial and expansive unless you are an academic),
- Gurobi (commercial),
- GLPK (free, but slow)...

I wrote two models below in pseudo-mathematical language below (note this is not LP format).

### Hard bounds

Let N be the set of your objects, X_min and Y_min the lower bound you need to reach and ZZ the average lower bound for the Z values.
I use a binary variable s_i whose value is 1 if the object i is selected, and 0 otherwise. The exact problem can be written as:

```
Minimize sum_{i in N} s_i
Subject to:
      sum_{i in N} X_i s_i >= X_min
      sum_{i in N} Y_i s_i >= Y_min
      sum_{i in N} (Z_i - ZZ) s_i >= 0
      foreach i in N, s_i in {0, 1}
```

### Multi-objective

Note that there are other ways to do this, as stated by Andreas' answer.
This one is the easier (in my opinion) way to prioritize your goals and "relax" the problem, and you can use the linear solvers above.

You add three slack variables dX, dY, dZ, and three (positive) weight coefficients wX, wY, wZ.
The variables dX, dY and dZ will represent the constraint violation, and the "weight" represents the importance you give to the constraint violation.

Then you can write the problem as:

```
Minimize sum_{i in N} s_i + wX dX + wY dY + wZ dZ
Subject to:
      dX >= sum_{i in N} X_i s_i - X_min
      dY >= sum_{i in N} Y_i s_i - Y_min
      dZ >= sum_{i in N} (Z_i - ZZ) s_i
      foreach i in N, s_i in {0, 1}
      dX, dY, dZ >= 0
```

Then, you can parametrize wX, wY and wZ in order to prioritize your goals: for instance, for large values of the weight, the model will return the "hard bound" solution if it exists; then, the constraint with the higther weight is "less likely" to be violated than the other (it is not exactly as simple of course, just to give an idea).